# Windows server 2008 active directory user profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts, user-profile

I just wanted to ask about profile migration.

There is Windows 2008 r2 server and people are working connected to this server through RDP. One user was deleted from active directory a long time ago but that profile files (user account) is still there. Is there a possibility to create new user in active directory and connect that new user to old users profile?

Comment: Look into profile migration tools... the ones I know of are intended to do exactly what you want for *workstations* - win7, 10...  But they might work for users on a server with RDP.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge, user profiles are based on a user objects GUID.  So no if you create another domain or local user with the same SAMAccountName and that user logs into that server a new profile folder will be created.

Comment: This is correct, except its the accounts SID that the profile will be tied to. You could ultimately copy the existing profile into the new users folder post first logon and have them receive their old profile. The NTUSER.dat file that holds the users registry and all the software settings in AppData would be transferred over. This is not a perfect method, but I have had success in the past with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the deleted user using LDP.exe

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmukGENyJPU